# My code works but my program doesn't, How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, winforms

There is one part in the variables which doesn't read:

```
decimal convertedDistance = Convert.ToDecimal(tbOutput.Text);
```

now I believe I understand that I have caused the textbox output to be a number inserted by a user rather than a result which is supposed to be given.

I've tried multiple ways to fix this, but am not getting through, is there anyone that can help me with my form of coding?

```
/*Distance Converter.
* In the English measurement system, 1 yard equals 3 feet and 1 foot equals 12 inches.
* Use this information to create an application that let's the user convert distances to and from inches, feet, and yards.
* The user enters the distance to be converted into a TextBox.
* A Listbox allows the user to select the units being converted from,
* and another ListBox allows the user to select the units being converted to.
* Note: Be sure to handle the situation where the user picks the asme units from both list boxes.
* The converted calue will be the same as the value entered. */

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _26DistanceConverter
{

   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void btExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Application.Exit();
      }

      private void btConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         //1ft = 12" - ft to inch 1"                        1/12ft - inch to ft
         //1 yard - 3 feet - yard to ft  1ft                1/3 yards - ft to yard
         //1 yard = 3 (ft) x 12" - yard to inch             1" = 1/ (3x12) - inch to yard

         const decimal inchToFoot = 1m / 12m;
         const decimal inchToYard = 1m / (3m * 12m);
         const decimal footToInch = 12m;
         const decimal footToYard = 1m/ 3m;
         const decimal yardToInch = 3m * 12m;
         const decimal yardToFoot = 3m;
         //tb Distance Covered equals txtInput
         decimal distanceToConvert = Convert.ToDecimal(tbDistanceCovered.Text);
         //tb Output = txtOutput

         ***decimal convertedDistance = Convert.ToDecimal(tbOutput.Text);***

         string from = LstFrom.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper();
         string to = LstTo.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper();
         tbDistanceCovered.Text = Convert.ToString("n2" + tbOutput.Text);

         if (from == "Inches" && to == "Feet")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert * inchToFoot;
         }
         else if (from == "Inches" && to == "Yards")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert * inchToYard;
         }
         else if (from == "Feet" && to == "Inches")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert * footToInch;
         }
         else if (from == "Feet" && to == "Yards")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert * footToYard;
         }
         else if (from == "Yards" && to == "Inches")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert * yardToInch;
         }
         else if (from == "Yards" && to == "Feet")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert * yardToFoot;
         }
         else if (from == "Yards" && to == "Yards")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert;
         }
         else if (from == "Inches" && to == "Inches")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert;
         }
         else if (from == "Feet" && to == "Feet")
         {
            convertedDistance = distanceToConvert; //when using same units
         }
         else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number", "Invalid Input");
      }

      private void btClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         LstFrom.ClearSelected();
         LstTo.ClearSelected();
         tbOutput.Clear();
         tbDistanceCovered.Clear();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: You should be assigning the result to the textbox rather than reading from it: `decimal convertedDistance = 0; ..... tbOutput.Text = convertedDistance.ToString();`

Comment: Also, you have `string from = LstFrom.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper(); (...)` then `if (from == "Inches" && to == "Feet")`. It should be `if (from == "INCHES" && to == "FEET")`. Otherwise the strings won't ever match.

Comment: not the answer to your question, but decimal is meant to be used with money. for distance you want a float, or if you need more precision a double. decimal will round your answers slightly, spread over more and more conversion this makes your model innacurate

Comment: @Vanethrane That's not true.  Decimal *prevents* rounding errors because it stores the data in base-10 rather than a base-2 approximation.  Decimal is the right data type here to help prevent issues where 12 inches equals 1.0000000001 feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
private void btConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // put this in the begining
    decimal convertedDistance = 0;

    // rest of your code will provide a value for convertedDistance 


    // and at the end put the value in output textbox with desired formatting
    tbOutput.Text = distanceToConvert.ToString("#.##");
}
```

also remember to remove these lines:

```
decimal convertedDistance = Convert.ToDecimal(tbOutput.Text);
```

and

```
tbDistanceCovered.Text = Convert.ToString("n2" + tbOutput.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes the  tbDistanceCovered.Text = Convert.ToString("n2" + tbOutput.Text); was there by accident was trying to correct my code and left it there.

decimal convertedDistance = Convert.ToDecimal(tbOutput.Text); this was my problem i have corrected it now by placing

tbOutput.Text = convertedDistance.ToString("n2"); into every single if statement

i have changed my variables
decimal convertedDistance; 
         string from = LstFrom.SelectedItem.ToString(); (no Upper)

         string to = LstTo.SelectedItem.ToString();

Works, thank you for your time and help

Comment: glad it helped. you may as well mark this as answer.

Comment: where? looking for it can't find it